# Jquery- buttons clicking can't get any result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created my button trigger to load items without refreshing page, so the result, it's like a row of the table, every row have a button and  every button have a different value and all of the buttons have the same id.
So the problem is when I click on any button from my result to do some tasks nothing happened, this is my code snippet what's wrong with it.

```js
function orderRegulation() {
    $("#new-projects").replaceWith(jQuery('#orderRegulation').show());
    $.getJSON('/orderRegulation', function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem('myResults', data);
        onQueueItems = ""
        data.forEach(element => {
            onQueueItems =
                '<tr><td>' +
                '#' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<a>' + element.id +
                '</a>' +
                '<br>' +
                '<small>' +
                'Completed: ' + element.date_completed +
                '</small>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<ul class="list-inline">' +
                '<li class="list-inline-item">' +
                '<img alt="Avatar" class="table-avatar" src="../../dist/img/haiak_logo.jpg">' +
                '</li>' +
                '<br>' +
                '<small>' +
                element.store.shop_name +
                '</small>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<ul class="list-inline"><h3>' +
                element.total +
                '</h3></ul>' +
                '</td>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<h3><u>' + (element.total * 90) / 100 +
                '</u></h3>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="project-state">' +
                '<span class="badge badge-success">Completed</span>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="project-actions text-right">' +
                '<button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-lgs" value="' + element.id + '">Do task</button>' +
                '</td></tr>';
        });
        $("#Order_on_queue").replaceWith(htmltest);
    });
}

$(document).on('click', 'test', function () {
    var ident = $(this).val();
    console.log(ident);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="card-body p-0" style="display: block;">
    <table class="table table-striped projects">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 1%">
                    #
                </th>
                <th style="width: 20%">
                    Order Number
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Store Name
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Total
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Store 90%
                </th>
                <th style="width: 8%" class="text-center">
                    Status
                </th>
                <th style="width: 20%">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="Order_on_queue">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    #
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a>
                        Loading ...
                    </a>
                    <br>
                    <small>
                        Completed: Loading ...
                    </small>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        Loading ...
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        Loading ...
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td class="project_progress">
                    Loading ...
                    </small>
                </td>
                <td class="project-state">
                    Loading..
                </td>
                <td class="project-actions text-right">
                    <div class="btn-group" id="loaditems">
                        <button type="button" id="your_button_id" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#modal-lgs" value="000">Helooo</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `id="test"` use `class="test"` and then change your selector to `$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {`